# JavaCUP - How to convert this line of EBNF to CFG Grammar?

Tags: context-free-grammar, ebnf

I posted a couple days ago about converting EBNF grammar to CFG. Well I think I have the jist of it now, but I'm a bit stuck on this particular one:

How would you convert:

```
MultiplicativeExpr -> PrimaryExpr (( '*' | '/' ) PrimaryExpr)*
```

to CFG?

My attempt here is to get rid of the * at the end (which means 0 or more) and replace it with a recursive way of writing it.

Answer (score 0):

You have the correct idea. Using an additional variable (recursive), you can do it like this:

```
MultiplicativeExpr -> PrimaryExpr SignExprList
SignExprList -> ε | '*' PrimaryExpr SignExprList | '/' PrimaryExpr SignExprList
```

Of course this isn't the only way, for example you could also do something like `Sign -> '*' | '/'`, and use that in `SignExprList`...